# Java - ClassNotFound Exception when working with ObjectInputStream and ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

I'm trying to move the contents of an ArrayList from the client to the server. When trying to readObject() the input I receive a ClassNotFoundException. Here is my code, along with the stack trace:

Client:

```
 ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
 ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
 for (Person p : people) {
    output.writeObject(p);
 }
```

Server:

```
 ArrayList<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();
 ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
 employees = (ArrayList<Employee>) input.readObject(); //Line 47
```

Error from server:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Person
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at Server.<init>(Server.java:47)
at ServerGUI.main(ServerGUI.java:143)
```

Comment: The message is pretty clear: your deserializing server doesn't have the Person class in its classpath.

Comment: Your server's class loader is not aware of the `Person` class.

Comment: Can someone clarify? It shouldn't have Person though, as these two will be run on different machines.

Comment: @JonPerron: How is your server JVM supposed to create an instance of Person, that has been serialized by the client, if it doesn't know the Person class? BTW, how do you intend the list of persons to magically become a list of employees? If you put apples in a box and send the box to a friend, the friend won't find bananas in the box.

Comment: It has an Employee class similar to Person. Employee has all of the variables Person has, along with position and salary. That is my reasoning behind casting readObject() to employee and the arraylist. Honestly I thought that'd work :/

Comment: I changed the name of Employee to Person and it worked 100%. BUT I need it to be called employee as my assignment entails.

Comment: Two classes that are "similar", but don't have the same name, are not the same class. When deserializing an object from the stream of bytes, the class name Person is in the stream of bytes, and Java thus tries to create an instance of Person. The fact that another class exists, named Employee, is completely irrelevant. You need to use the **same** class (either Person, or Employee) in the client and the server.

Comment: What you may want to do is make a constructor for an employee that takes a person, get the person in to the server then use it to construct an employee.